# Read data from port get result fickle data

Tags: php, serial-port, ascii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP preg_match to get a word after space, which is where it a word KG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032707/php-preg-match-to-get-a-word-after-space-which-is-where-it-a-word-kg)

I'm developing web application with PHP,My apps is communicate with scale digital, i'm using help with phpserial class.
My problem is data is output in my browser mistmatch with output in scale digital.
When in scale digital is **16KG**, so in browser output is **NT,ST+16KG** and then i refresh again the browser get other, like **~!NT,ST+16KG, 16KG**.
My question, how to get data in browser just **16KG**.

This is script to read data:

```
<?php
$serial = new phpSerial();
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyUSB1");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600); //Baud rate: 9600 
$serial->confParity("none"); //Parity (this is the "N" in "8-N-1") 
$serial->confCharacterLength(8); //Character length (this is the "8" in "8-N-1") 
$serial->confStopBits(1); //Stop bits (this is the "1" in "8-N-1") 
$serial->confFlowControl("none"); 

$serial->deviceOpen();

$serial->sendMessage(chr(1));
$tes = $serial->readPort();
print_r($tes);
// get result ~!NT,ST+16KG, 16KG or NT,ST+16KG
$serial->deviceClose();
?>
```

And this is code function readPort from class phpSerial.

```
function readPort ($count = 0)  {
        if ($this->_dState !== SERIAL_DEVICE_OPENED)
        {
            trigger_error("Device must be opened to read it", E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }

            $content = ""; $i = 0;

            if ($count !== 0)
            {
                do {
                    if ($i > $count) $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, ($count - $i));
                    else $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, 128);
                } while (($i += 128) === strlen($content));
            }
            else
            {
                do {
                    $content .= fread($this->_dHandle, 128);
                } while (($i += 128) === strlen($content));
            }

            return $content;
    }
```

I'm developing use linux, port scale digital detect in /dev/ttyUSB1, i mean this problem is ASCII, so any help me with my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Band-aid fix: `preg_replace("/(\d+KG)\z/", "$1", $str);`

Comment: Will it always be in KG?

Comment: Hi alex thanks for reply, if using parsing the data as it can not, because the result fickle if i refresh. example data result is NT,ST+16KG, and then i refresh browser again and then get result NT,ST+16KG-6K, and then i refresh again ~NT,ST+16KG~, and then i refresh again example NT,ST+16KG+16KG+16KG, and so forth, but there is between 16KG.

Comment: Hi cryptic, thanks for reply. yes, there is always between KG, is there a moment in your regex issue. or better yet directly alter the function readPort.

Comment: I love google translate ..