# PHP preg_match to get a word after space, which is where it a word KG

Tags: php

I have a string that is uncertain,I have the following strings:
 `ST,NT,+ 16KG ~YT,NT,+ 16KG`
`ST,NT) 16KG +YT,N,+ 16KG`
`ST,NT,+ 16KG` and etc.

My question is there any regex only take **16KG** or **16**, because the string output from  digital scale.
I'm working on an application with serial port, so I can not parsing the data there, while in the output on digital scale tool is only `16KG`.

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read data from port get result fickle data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015683/read-data-from-port-get-result-fickle-data)

Comment: Mario there i get no answer, you can see who is quest there.

Comment: Hi all, this issue is over, thank you've helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get the digits before `KG`?

try this:

```
<?php
    $input = 'ST,NT,+ 16KG ~YT,NT,+ 16KG';
    preg_match('/(\d+)KG/',$input,$matches);
    echo $matches[1];
?>
```

output:

```
16
```

Comment: Hi owen, thanks for reply, i get error, when i print_r($matches) i get array with empty data.

Comment: can you show your full code? My code did work for your sample inputs: http://ideone.com/nTYDSa

Comment: I want to ask one question again, what if on output digital scale will be a minus with regex above, for example -2KG, and then example i get string is 'ST,NT,+ -2KG ~YT,NT,+ -2KG', i tried, and it only show 2KG, without minus it.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to allow minus, change `(\d+)` to `(-?\d+)`

Comment: Hi Mr Barmar this work for me, many2 thanks for Mr Barmar and Mr Owen, i give you thumb up. Thanks.